# How to write a PCRE regular expression to find a string with different content?

Tags: regex, pcre

This may be a simple one but I can't seem to find the answer to it.

I have a string in a HTML file that I am looking for:

```
<div class="button" onclick="document.$name.submit(); return false\">Save</div>
```

where $name is is generated by code, so can be anything.

I need to write a PCRE regular expression that will find this string in the file but disregard the $name section of the string.

I have tried this :

```
/<div class=\"button\" document.(.+?).submit\(\); return false\">Save<\/div>/
```

It will return the group that equals to what is in $name. but not define it as a match, which is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
/<div class="button" onclick="document\.(.+?)\.submit\(\); return false">Save<\/div>/
```

Most likely your problem was that you forgot to escape the parenthesis after `submit()`, so it tried to match `submit;`.

Comment: this is sort of what I am looking for...but! this will return a group of whatever is in $name, but will not match it.

Comment: so if the string was this 'document.buttonform.submit()' then I would get no match but would have a group with the value 'buttonform' I am using phpunits expectOutputRegex() which is looking for a matched outcome

Comment: expectOutputRegex seems to use assertRegexp() internally, which basically checks if preg_match() returns more than 0, so it should work, but I've tried here and it seems that php5.3.0 fails at recognizing ';'s in regular expressions.  Try . instead of ; (I've updated the regex above)

Comment: opps my bad.....was Looking for 'Save' where it should have been 'Update', so now is return as a match cos it finds it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@<div class="button" onclick="document.(.*?).submit\(\); return false">Save</div>@
```

Comment: While this will match, consider escaping the literal `.`'s and using `(.+?)`